# Bregman Mean of a Distribution

Tags: risk, coherent-risk-measure

In a paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6677.pdf)), author writes, given that $\gamma:R\rightarrow \bar{R}$ is a convex function, $dom_{\gamma}:=\{x\in R:\gamma(x)<+\infty\}$ is a non-empty open set and $\gamma$ a closed proper differentiable function in the interior of $dom_{\gamma}$, $d$ is [Bregman divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence) $$d_{\gamma}(x,x')=\gamma(x)-\gamma(x')-\gamma'(x')(x-x')$$ Define the **Bregman mean** as the unique point $b$ in the support of $\mu$ satisfying $$\int d_{\gamma}(b,x)\mu(dx)=\min_{m\in dom_{\gamma}}\int d_{\gamma}(m,x)\mu(dx)$$.

He says that it is very easy to obtain $b$ by differentiating:
$b=\gamma'^{-1}[\int\gamma'(x)\mu(dx)]$.

Can anyone explain to me the definition and how he gets the formula for $b$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align*}
f(m) &= \int d_{\gamma}(m,x)\mu(dx)\\
&=\int \big[\gamma(m)-\gamma(x)-\gamma'(x)(m-x)\big]\mu(dx)\\
&=\gamma(m) - \int \big[\gamma(x)+\gamma'(x)(m-x)\big]\mu(dx).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dm} = \gamma'(m) - \int \gamma'(x)\mu(dx),
\end{align*}
and the critical point is given by
\begin{align*}
b = \big(\gamma'\big)^{-1}\Big( \int \gamma'(x)\mu(dx)\Big).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I want to add that the point b is unique because $\gamma$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks @DavidNguyen. That is correct, and $b$ is therefore the optimal point.